# C# asp.net GridView displaying all rows in table as "Databound"

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on an asp.net web application to display table data from an existing database. When I drag the table into the design view of my web form, "Databound" is displayed. The table properties are displayed correctly though. What could be the cause of this?

Visual Studio 2012,
Sql Server 2012 Express,
C#,
Asp.net Empty Web Application

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/la0otsd3kkhgq3r/Screenshot_2.png)

Comment: How do you want display data? Your question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

This is the design view... It's not actually pulling data. Hit f5 and browse to your page.

Comment: You can say this in comment itself...

Comment: @VigneshKumar The question is "What could be the cause of this".  This is the cause and the solution to viewing the data in the grid by hitting f5.  This is a question answer forum where you get points by answering questions.  So here we are...